# Show numeric keyboard with alphanumeric switching option

Tags: android, keyboard

Hello can anyone tell me how to show the following keyboard layout pragmatically in android.

[image: 1]

Comment: do you want to show this type of keyboard when adding input to edit text?

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary Yap i want to show this exact keyboard layout when adding input to edit text. Then user may change the keyboard layout as he/she want by tapping ABC or @?#.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than choosing the type of keyboard consider setting the input type in the editText via:

```
android:inputType="XXXXXXX"
```

(Doing this can change the type of keyboard that appears when you want to provide input to the editText)

Replace the XXXXX text with any of [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#TextView_inputType) values according to your use case.

You can also add the `android:imeOptions="XXXXXX"` attribute to your editText.
Replace XXXXXX with any of [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:imeOptions) values.

You can learn more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style)